# Clipboard shows it has "Dib" format but it cannot fetch it?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, clipboard

I am trying to get a `bool` value if an image/picture copied to the clipboard contains any transparency and for that I am using [this answer](https://github.com/skoshy/CopyTransparentImages/blob/304e383b8f3239496999087421545a9b4dc765e5/ConsoleApp2/Program.cs#L79), which I found on GitHub. It will get the picture in the clipboard in the `DataFormats.Dib` format and then iterate over that in a `byte[]` array to check for transparency.

My problem is that for certain images, then the clipboard data return `null` though the clipboard states it does contain the format!? I cannot figure out what is wrong and why it behaves like this on some images. I have the below example code:

```
// This will return "true" on my problematic image
bool hasDibFormat = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Dib);

if (hasDibFormat)
{
    // This will return "null" on my problematic image
    var dib = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Dib);
}
```

In the real code then this line is the problem for me:

```
// Line "84" in the attached code
dib = ((System.IO.MemoryStream)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Dib)).ToArray();
```

... and I get this error when copying an image from *Outlook* - but only for some pictures:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

The image where I have a problem has these formats:

[image: Picture formats]

Any insights would be appreciated :-)

Comment: What's on the clipboard is a function of whatever the tool it was that copied data to the clipboard.  It may have lied.  How does your image get on the clipboard (i.e., did you copy it from a browser, from Word, did a program you wrote put it there)?

Comment: I am copying a picture in an Outlook email. I don't understand how the clipboard can "lie" - this sounds weird to me?

Comment: When you put something on the clipboard, you have to set up the FORMATETC and STGMEDIUM information (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/data-formats-and-transfer-media).  Bugs happen.  It's unlikely that Outlook has that class of bug, but...

Comment: I'd check if the Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Dib) returns value before the cast, perhaps u'll get your answer there

Comment: Which cast are you referring to? I am not casting anything in my example code and it does return `true`.

Comment: This is a cast: `(System.IO.MemoryStream)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Dib)`. What @Flydog57 said is to take into consideration, you need to test the Bitmap object, with, e.g., `bool is COMObj = Marshal.IsComObject([IDataObject].GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, false));`. In that case, you need to build a `FORMATETC` struct, with `cfFormat = 2`, `dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT` and `tymed = TYMED.TYMED_GDI`. Then `[IDataObject].GetData(ref formatEtc, out STGMEDIUM stgMedium);` and get the Bitmap with `Image.FromHbitmap(stgMedium.unionmember);`

Comment: `FORMATETC` and `STGMEDIUM` are all part of the Interop assembly (`System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes`). Getting COM objects from Office apps is quite common. The Dib can be null, `System.Drawing.Bitmap` usually isn't (and that's often moved around as a COM object).

Comment: The .NET Framework makes interacting with the Clipboard really easy (compared to C++ and COM).  Everything works so easily, right up until it doesn't.  Then you need to do interop contortions

Comment: My problematic image shows `false` with the `isCOMObj` code, so I assume it is not a COM object? My code: `bool isCOMObj = Marshal.IsComObject( Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, false));`. I don't think I understand this enough to implement it - would it be possible for you to suggest an answer with some more elaborative comments in it?

Comment: If the object returned retrieving the `Bitmap` Format is not null and not a COM object, you can get it with `var bitmap = (Bitmap)[IDataObject].GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, false);`